# Validation to site.domain fieald

Tags: python, django

I import 
**from django.contrib.sites.models import Site**  in models.py file.

In have this following in admin.py file:

```
class SitesAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):    
    pass

admin.site.unregister(Site)
admin.site.register(Site, SitesAdmin)**
```

I want to attach validation to the `site.domain` field in admin.py, How i can accomplish this? please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, specifying an empty `ModelAdmin` class is unnecessary, the following will work if you don't need to customize the admin:

```
admin.site.register(Site) # Notice that no ModelAdmin is passed
```

Now, to your question. You have to create a custom form. Then, you override the `clean_domain` method of the `ModelForm`. You can validate any field with the method(s) `clean_FOO`, where `FOO` is the field name.

```
from django import forms

class SiteAdminForm(forms.ModelForm):

    def clean_domain(self):
        domain = self.cleaned_data.get('domain')
        # Custom validation here

        return domain

class SiteAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = SiteAdminForm

admin.site.unregister(Site)
admin.site.register(Site, SiteAdmin)
```